# JsonUtils Exception with JavaScript Overlay Type List in GWT

Tags: javascript, json, gwt

I get a JSON String from a Servlet und want to parse this string using JavaScript Overlay Types.

My whole coding oriented on thy examples published by [google](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html#javascript-objects)
My Goal is to load the JSON String into an ArrayList of Type Article.

So I created the Class JSArray

```
public class JsArray<E extends JavaScriptObject> extends JavaScriptObject {
    protected JsArray() { }
    public final native int length() /*-{ return this.length; }-*/;
    public final native E get(int i) /*-{ return this[i];     }-*/;
}
```

The class ArticleData

```
public class ArticleData extends JavaScriptObject {
    protected ArticleData() {}

    public final native String getId() /*-{ return this.id; }-*/;
    public final native String getAmount() /*-{ return this.amount; }-*/;
    public final native String getPct() /*-{ return this.pct; }-*/;
    public final native String getStartAmount() /*-{ return this.startamount; }-*/;
    public final native String getPrice() /*-{ return this.price; }-*/;
    public final native String getStockValue() /*-{ return this.stockvalue; }-*/;
}
```

And in my EntryPoint I both classes to following way:

```
String json = event.getResults();
logger.info(json);

JsArray<ArticleData> cs = getArticles(json);
for (int i = 0, n = cs.length(); i < n; ++i) {
    Window.alert(cs.get(i).getId() + " " + cs.get(i).getPrice());
}

...
private native JsArray<ArticleData> getArticles(String json)/*-{
   return JsonUtils.safeEval(json);
}-*/;
```

My JSON file:

```
{"articles":[
{"amount":"50","id":"1","pct":"50,00","price":"162,37","startamount":"100","stockvalue":"8118,45"},{"amount":"20","id":"2","pct":"20,00","price":"164,83","startamount":"100","stockvalue":"3296,60"},{"amount":"20","id":"3","pct":"20,00","price":"170,40","startamount":"100","stockvalue":"3408,00"},{"amount":"100","id":"4","pct":"100,00","price":"41,32","startamount":"100","stockvalue":"4132,43"},{"amount":"0","id":"5","pct":"0,00","price":"40,04","startamount":"100","stockvalue":"0,00"}]}
```

I always get this exception:

> Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException:
>   (ReferenceError): JsonUtils is not defined
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>       at net.mybecks.gwt.client.XMLParser.getArticles(XMLParser.java)
>       at net.mybecks.gwt.client.XMLParser.access$2(XMLParser.java:92)
>       at net.mybecks.gwt.client.XMLParser$2.onSubmitComplete(XMLParser.java:78)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel$SubmitCompleteEvent.dispatch(FormPanel.java:115)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel$SubmitCompleteEvent.dispatch(FormPanel.java:1)
>       at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)

Line 92 is the getArticles method from above.

I strictly following the google documentation, and I don't find any helpful results in googleing the exception. Only Class Documetations.

BR & Thanks,
mybecks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is `getArticles()` a JSNI method? `JsonUtils` is a normal GWT class.

Your method should be:

```
private JsArray<ArticleData> getArticles(String json) {
   return JsonUtils.safeEval(json);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not advocating this approach, Strelok's is certainly better, but your issue came from not explicitly referencing JsonUtils.

```
private native JsArray<ArticleData> getArticles(String json)/*-{
    return @com.google.gwt.core.client.JsonUtils::safeEval(Ljava/lang/String;)(json);
}-*/
```

See [Calling a Java Method from Handwritten JavaScript](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling)